# Generating response based on form data without using server?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML document with lots of iterations of the following

```
<form>
Question 
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="563430" value="correct">
Answer1 </input> <br/>
<input type="radio" name="563430" value="incorrect">
Answer2 </input> <br/> 
<input type="radio" name="563430" value="incorrect">
Answer3 </input><br/>
<input type="radio" name="563430" value="incorrect">
Answer4 </input><br/>
<input type="radio" name="563430" value="incorrect">
Answer5 </input><br/>
<br/>

(another dozen of those or so)

</form>
```

How can I (without sending data to a webserver) interpret the number of correct and divide it by the number of total answered questions?

Thanks

EDIT: this html came from an xml sheet modified with xsl

Comment: Use javascript to do any client side operation.

Comment: You know which inputs are correct, and you know which inputs are selected-- iterate over the lot of them and add up your totals.  Keep in mind, though-- if the UI knows which answers are correct, then so can anybody with a little know-how regarding development tools.

Comment: I'm not that experienced with JS at all (or really web scripting) so what with this look like? @anied

Comment: You can use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to iterate over the DOM.  If you are very green you can try getting started with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) instead-- it has a more shallow learning curve.  StackOverflow is here to give you answers to specific questions or issues you are having-- it seems like perhaps you are more in need of something closer to a tutorial.  For vanilla JavaScript, it's hard to beat [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) as a free tutorial resource.

Comment: Note, `<input>` tag is self-closing. `</input>` is not valid `html`.

Comment: @anied _"If you are very green you can try getting started with jQuery instead"_ `jquery` tag does not appear at Question.

Comment: Thanks for the help @anied this is for an IB Computer Science SL project, so I don't believe security would be a huge issue. edit: i'm going substantially more in depth than what is required, so that's why I'm pretty confused lol.

Comment: @guest271314 -- I know, but this user seems a bit out of his or her depth, and I'm trying to provide good starting points to self-teach rather than write them a solution out of whole-cloth.  If vanilla JS isn't as important to them as completing the task quickly, jQuery may be a good option for them.  If they had posted "how do I make this <h1> element red?" and not included a `CSS` tag, I certainly wouldn't have pointed them to a `<font>` element :)  I would mention tools that might be useful to them.

Comment: @anied Which advantage does jQuery ultimately have when compared to `DOM` `javascript` methods? The ability to chain the methods? Using jQuery does not decrease the potential of further questions arising as to jQuery usage; followed by the possibility in future of query "how to do xyz using JavaScript (DOM methods), without jQuery?". Have not searched, though also cannot convey that have viewed any  Questions at SO where "how to do xyz using jQuery, without JavaScript (DOM methods)?" was included in title of Question.

Comment: @guest271314 - simple selector engine, less need to concern one's self with browser support, chained methods, wide user-base with a big support network for beginners, etc.  Personally, I prefer to use plain JavaScript, and jQuery certainly comes with its own big "cons" column, but it's a good option for beginners and people for who are not necessarily looking to make a career in front end dev but may need to dabble very occasionally-- imo, failing to mention it as an option therein would have been remiss.

Comment: @anied _"imo, failing to mention it as an option therein would have been remiss."_? Should each `javascript` Question have a jQuery footnote where jQuery is not explicitly mentioned within the body of the Question of at tags?

Comment: @guest271314 -- no, I don't think so.  Probably the best option would be for SO commenters to use their best judgement on when it might be helpful to mention it to posters who seem new to front end development :)

Comment: @anied "new to front end development" !== "needs more jQuery" . Perhaps reference w3c, whatwg `DOM` and ecmascript specifications first?

Comment: @guest271314 - I fear we may have to agree to disagree on this one.  I understand the push back against overuse/overprescription of jQuery, and perhaps you are correct that if jQuery isn't tagged it doesn't belong here.  However, I made a judgement call that this user might not be aware of jQuery and might be well served seeing it as an option-- I'd prefer to be helpful over pedantic, but that is absolutely an opinion-based decision, and choosing to closely follow protocol over being helpful has its own merits.  Unless I'm violating rules, though, I'm standing by my decision to mention jQuery.